# Writing a Python Program to Leverage Google AutoML for Entity Extraction

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to leverage Google's AutoML Natural Language to extract entities from PDF documents, and exported those entities and associated values into csv files. I have already trained an entity extraction model on the AutoML UI, and am now working on writing a Python program to invoke the model and perform the post processing task.

Here, I am just experimenting with writing some simple code to predict the extracted entities on a pdf file. However, I am running into some issues and would like some help; below is my code:

```
import sys
import os

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import automl_v1

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/Users/jetsonwu/intelligent-upload/AutoML_NLP/GCP/automl-pipeline-354119-bc09422edc36.json"

model_id = "TEN7692325184920879104"
file_path = "gs://intelligent_upload/electric-bill/pdf/China World Trade Center EB1.pdf"

def inline_text_payload(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
        content = ff.read()
    return {'text_snippet': {'content': content, 'mime_type': 'text/plain'} }

def pdf_payload(file_path):
    return {'document': {'input_config': {'gcs_source': {'input_uris': [file_path] } } } }

def get_prediction(file_path, model_name):
    options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='us-automl.googleapis.com')
    prediction_client = automl_v1.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)

    # payload = inline_text_payload(file_path)
    # Uncomment the following line (and comment the above line) if want to predict on PDFs.
    payload = pdf_payload(file_path)
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name=model_name, payload=payload, params=params)
    return request  # waits until request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    model_name = sys.argv[2]

    print(get_prediction(file_path, model_id))
```

The code above is pretty much copied straight from the AutoML UI, but I am getting some errors and could not figure out why... Here is the error message:

```
E0627 22:10:44.828979000 4336043392 hpack_parser.cc:1234]              Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value key=content-type value=text/html; charset=UTF-8

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py:50, in _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     49 try:
---> 50     return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     51 except grpc.RpcError as exc:

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:946, in _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.__call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
    944 state, call, = self._blocking(request, timeout, metadata, credentials,
    945                               wait_for_ready, compression)
--> 946 return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:849, in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
    848 else:
--> 849     raise _InactiveRpcError(state)

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
    details = "Received http2 header with status: 404"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1656382244.829029000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.191.234:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":967,"grpc_message":"Received http2 header with status: 404","grpc_status":12}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MethodNotImplemented                      Traceback (most recent call last)
...
     50     return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     51 except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 52     raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc

MethodNotImplemented: 501 Received http2 header with status: 404
```

For the file path, I am using one of the pdf file that I have previously uploaded to cloud storage. Would anyone please take a look and help? Much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using `us-automl.googleapis.com`, can you try using `automl.googleapis.com` for `api_endpoint` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to replicate your scenario and make a solution based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/locations#setting_the_location_using_the_api):

> AutoML Natural Language supports both a global API endpoint (automl.googleapis.com) and a European Union endpoint (eu-automl.googleapis.com).

I changed the api_endpoint from `us-automl.googleapis.com` to `automl.googleapis.com`. Also I modified `model_id` including the path. See working code below:

```py
import sys
import os

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import automl_v1

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/<your-path>/tiph-anjelab-318a5dcad3c6.json"

model_id = "projects/<>/locations/us-central1/models/<your-model-id>"
file_path = "<your-path>/test.txt"

def inline_text_payload(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
        content = ff.read()
    return {'text_snippet': {'content': content, 'mime_type': 'text/plain'} }

def pdf_payload(file_path):
    return {'document': {'input_config': {'gcs_source': {'input_uris': [file_path] } } } }

def get_prediction(file_path, model_name):
    options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='automl.googleapis.com')
    prediction_client = automl_v1.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)

    payload = inline_text_payload(file_path)
    # Uncomment the following line (and comment the above line) if want to predict on PDFs.
    #payload = pdf_payload(file_path)
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name=model_name, payload=payload, params=params)
    return request  # waits until request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #file_path = sys.argv[1]
    #model_name = sys.argv[2]

    print(get_prediction(file_path, model_id))
```

Output:

```
payload {
  annotation_spec_id: "6167291562079289344"
  display_name: "Modifier"
  text_extraction {
    score: 0.996536374092102
    text_segment {
      start_offset: 13
      end_offset: 39
      content: "hereditary hemochromatosis"
    }
  }
}
payload {
  annotation_spec_id: "1555605543651901440"
  display_name: "DiseaseClass"
  text_extraction {
    score: 0.9985179901123047
    text_segment {
      start_offset: 180
      end_offset: 207
      content: "autosomal recessive disease"
    }
  }
}
payload {
  annotation_spec_id: "2708527048258748416"
  display_name: "SpecificDisease"
  text_extraction {
    score: 0.999455988407135
    text_segment {
      start_offset: 208
      end_offset: 234
      content: "hereditary hemochromatosis"
    }
  }
}
payload {
  annotation_spec_id: "6167291562079289344"
  display_name: "Modifier"
  text_extraction {
    score: 0.9980571269989014
    text_segment {
      start_offset: 2323
      end_offset: 2349
      content: "hereditary hemochromatotic"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Thank you so so much Anjela :)